# Deriving Tables from ER diagram

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

How many tables could be derived from the below ER diagram.
[image]

**Bank( phn_no, Code, Name, addr)**

{phn_no,Code} is candidate key

**Branches( Code, Branch_no)**

{branch_no} is the key, {Branch_no} is the foreign key to BankBranch, and {code} violates foreign key constraint.

**BankBranch(Branch_no,Branch Name, Addr)**

{Branch_no} is the key

**Loan(Loan_no,Amount,Type,Branch_no)**

{Loan_no} is the key and {Branch_no} is the foreign key to BankBranch.

I known Branches can't be merged into BankBranch because after combining Branches into BankBranch {code} foreign key integrity is voilated.

So, how many tables could be derived from the above ER model.

Comment: Hi. Please state the relevant principles/methods/transformations taught in your particular class/textbook re this sort of question. Do you understand that this design normally means 5 tables? (1 for each entity & relationship type.) I suppose you were told an N:1 relationship can be joined into the N side? But if the 2 "Addr"s had different names, we could use just 1 table--is renaming allowed? In general, we can keep joining on CKs--but--allowed? May we change attribute types to sets? But if so would that violate *your* "1NF"? *Say what your class allows for such (non-standard) questions.*

Comment: PS Please give a reference for this kind of ER diagram--methods & their diagram conventions differ. Typo: Phn_no. Also: Why do you think it's part of a CK? How are CKs indicated? (Sanity check: Do we need to give a bank code *plus a phone number* to identify a bank?) PS Does it make sense that a branch number would identify a particular branch of a particular bank? Does it make sense a bank name would be a branch attribute if it weren't also a CK of the bank?

Answer (score 0):

It Requires 4 Tables to represent Above ER.(i.e Bank,BankBranch ,Loan and **Contacts{Code,Phno.}** where code is referenced from code in bank)

Since Phno is multi valued attribute we requires extra entityset to store Phone Number of every bank.
And also table will be in 1NF(Atomic).

Hope it helps!!